# traefik docker x-forwarded-for loop

Tags: docker, rancher, traefik

I am having issues using docker + rancher + traefik.

The backends are discovered well and it works with 2 rancher hosts. But from time to time when hitting the my websites hosted in the traefik backend, I have docker that does a lot of io wait and the traefik logs shedding logs like:

```
my-internal-proxy-2     | 2018-02-06T15:03:15.500664406Z time="2018-02-06T15:03:15Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/forward: begin ServeHttp on request" Request="{"Method":"GET","URL":{"Scheme":"http","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":":80","Path":"","RawPath":"","ForceQuery":false,"RawQuery":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Accept":["*/*"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip"],"User-Agent":["curl/7.47.0"],"X-Forwarded-For":["public.ip.xx, 10.4.2.116, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1....
```

Why I am getting this? it crashed everyday and cannot figureout why x-forwarded-for is 127.0.0.1. any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Could you give more information? TOML, Docker & Rancher labels, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the redirect clause `[entryPoints.http.redirect]` in my toml, here is the good toml config:

```
[entryPoints]
 [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
   entrypoint = "https"
 [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

thanks a lot Idez from traefik support ;)

Answer (score 0):

here are more details:
latest docker-ce is used
toml:

```
debug = true
logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
[entryPoints.https.tls]
[web]
address = ":8080"
[docker]
[acme]
email = myemail@mydomain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
caServer = "https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[acme.dnsChallenge]
provider = "ovh"
delayBeforeCheck = 0
```

docker-compose in rancher:

```
  version: '2'
services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:v1.5.1
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
    command: --web --accessLog --constraints=tag==internal --rancher --rancher.exposedbydefault=false --rancher.metadata=true --logLevel=DEBUG
    volumes:
      - /data/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - /data/traefik/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
      - "io.rancher.container.agent.role: internal"
      - "environment io.rancher.container.create_agent: true"
    environment:
      - OVH_ENDPOINT=ovh-eu
      - OVH_APPLICATION_KEY=xxxx
      - OVH_APPLICATION_SECRET=xxxx
      - OVH_CONSUMER_KEY=xxx

  mediawiki:
    image: mediawiki:stable
    volumes:
            -
 /data/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
      - /var/www/html/images/
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
      - "traefik.backend=mediawiki"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wiki.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.tags=internal"
      - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
```